# Ellis Island immigration record handwriting help

Tags: united-states, records, immigration, palaeography

I've had an Ellis Island record for my great grandfather for several years, but have never been able to read the 'relative or friend's name and address' column for that record.  I'm hoping someone here can help me!

Here is the text I'm unable to read:

[image: Text I can't read]

and, for comparison, here is the rest of the row with my transcription.

[image: Ellis Island extract]

> Wolkind | Nathan | 29 | m | Printer | Russia | Father Mr Wolkind  622 Mile End Rd, London, E

Comment: Do you have higher resolution images you can share?

Comment: The first excerpt is the highest resolution I have.  Would a higher resolution copy of the second extract help?

Comment: @Flup Anything higher res would help. If the two snippets were written by the same person there may be pieces of the latter text that may help decipher the former...

Comment: Where did you obtain this image from? Maybe we could get a better view of it from the source file.

Comment: I've uploaded full-resolution versions of both pages to http://ian.chard.org/nathan0.gif and http://ian.chard.org/nathan1.gif.  The row I'm interested in is number 13.

Comment: You may know the last name as "Wolkind", but the Ellis Island recorder definitely wrote **Welkind** for both the father and son's name. You may want to search in North America for that form of the name.

Comment: Searching the US census before and after the date for that relevant address may help identify the friend.

Comment: Are there other pages in the manifest with this person's handwriting? A larger sample might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **607 E 11th Street, New York**. That is the site of an [apartment building](http://www.trulia.com/homes/New_York/New_York/sold/1000025867-607-E-11th-St-New-York-NY-10009#photo-1) constructed in the East Village around 1900.

Comment: Thanks for that!  It's obvious now I look at it.  But what I really want is the name :)

Comment: Great answer! @Flup, you said that you were interested in name and _address_. Now that Fortiter has given you the address, try searching for something similar to **R. Sendener**. This is what I can see. He is listed as a **Friend**.

Comment: A Google Search for the East Village address finds the reference at http://ian.chard.org/family/pafg04.htm#49. I am a little puzzled why I am searching for something that you already know!

Comment: The address is there, but @Flup has said he also wants the friend's name.

Comment: @Fortiter well found :) I forgot that I'd made a stab at the address beforehand, but it's good to have a verification of it, especially as you didn't see my attempt beforehand.

Comment: @Flup SE is not meant for discussion but you may want to revisit that work. Your description of the direction of migration on that page does not match the data sources mentioned here.

Answer (score 3):

All I can make out is:

Friend [R?] [*illegible*]

607[?]11<sup>th</sup> A[??], New York, NY.

Answer (score 3):

I see for the friend's name **S. Sende[rn|ree|ne|...][s|r|d]**. The letters within square brackets are dubious; the last letter has to be either s, r, or d, but it is impossible to tell which. I'm quite sure that his initial is S, based on other names and places with the same letter. So, amongst others, the following names are possible:

- Sendener
- Senderns
- Sendernd
- ...

It is also possible that the n's are u's, so perhaps Seudener is also possible...you don't happen to have this in a higher resolution and/or in colour?